# Creating AR model for Drupal database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, drupal, activerecord

how do I change my activerecord model default behavior for the find method?
For example, i want to search for all books inside drupal nodes database, but drupal uses only one table for all data, and uses the 'type' column to find out the type

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'node'

  def find(*args)
    :conditions => {:type => 'book'}
    super
  end
end
```

this is the correct approach to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using CCK (content contstruction kit, also known as content.module)? In that case your tables will be a lot more dynamic even.

Comment: yes, there are cck fields in this node type. But for instance i was just trying to get the book nodes.

I was planning to write a rails plugin, something like acts_as_drupal_node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this creating a model for Node and using named_scopes

the result was this

```
class Node
  set_table_name 'node'
  set_primary_key 'nid'
  named_scope :book, :conditions => {:type => 'book'}

  # if i don't overwrite this method, i would get an error when i try to use the type column
  def self.inheritance_column
    "rails_type"
  end
end
```

it works, but doesn't look like the rails way of doing stuff. If I get enought time soon, I'll try to write a library to access drupal data using something like acts_as_drupal_node

now i can fetch all book entries using:

```
@books = Node.book.all
```

Comment: In your case I will use **books**  as a name of scope, and in Rails 3 you can use `scope` not `named_scope`